# YARN min container size

Tags: mapreduce, containers, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Can someone explain me what would be the negative impact of setting the min container size to a small value like 512 MB for a cluster with 128GB per datanode?

MIN_CONTAINER_SIZE=

╔═════════════════════╦══════════════════════════╗
║  Total RAM per Node ║Recommended Min Container ║
╠═════════════════════╬══════════════════════════╣
║ Less than 4 GB      ║ 256 MB                   ║
║ Between 4 GB & 8 GB ║ 512 MB                   ║
║ Between 8 GB & 24 GB║ 1024 MB                  ║
║ Above 24 GB         ║ 2048 MB                  ║
╚═════════════════════╩══════════════════════════╝
What's the benefit of adhering to these guidelines?

What if we have jobs which process smaller amounts of data, wouldn't have a small yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb = 512 MB and a bigger
mapreduce.map.memory.mb = 4096 (even though this tipically is set to double the above parameter)
allow elasticity between a big number of containers and thus more splits, and having them grow quite bigger if needed?

Comment: Can you share the source of this table?